# Failed to drop column in cassandra using CQL

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I failed to drop column using CQL. Here is the error message I got:

`Bad Request: line 1:28 no viable alternative at input 'drop'`

Here is what I am doing.
I am running cassandra 1.2.6.
This is the way I created my keyspace:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE ex1 WITH replication = {
'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
'replication_factor': '1'
};
```

Then I switched to just created keyspace:

`use ex1`

After that I created the following table:

```
create table person ( id varchar, firstName varchar, lastName varchar, primary key (id));
```

Now I try to drop one column as following:

```
cqlsh:ex1> alter table person drop lastName;
Bad Request: line 1:19 no viable alternative at input 'drop'
```

Attempt using keyword `COLUMNFAMILY` instead of `TABLE` does not help as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `DELETE`? It will remove a column but it needs a `WHERE` clause, e.g., `DELETE lastName FROM person WHERE <clause>`.

Comment: @lorcan, `Delete` does not remove column. It removes values. I have to remove column itself from the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

drop doesn't work in Cassandra 1.2.x..  You need to use at least 2.0.0.

In 2.0, when you drop a column, it is immediately unavailable for queries but the data is still present.  The column is removed by subsequent compactions so eventually the space will be freed.

Comment: Thanks, @Richard. I'll upgrade cassandra and try again.

Answer (score 1):

@AlexR

Try **alter table person drop lastname;**

CQL3 is case-insensitive.

By the way, which version of Cassandra are you using ? I've seen somewhere that dropping column was not supported in early versions of CQL3

Comment: CQL3 case sensitivity is complicated. There's a nice explanation here: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/cql_lexicon. Keywords (like ALTER) are case insensitive. Identifiers (like firstName) are made lower case unless enclosed by double quotes. So case sensitivity isn't the problem here, it's that drop isn't supported in 1.2.x..

Comment: @doanduyhai, thank you. You are right, CQL is case-*insensitive*, so the case does not affect the result. Thanks anyway for you help